# strange error trying to compile Latex document

Tags: pdftex, textmate

Hello I am writing my thesis in Latex on Textmate 2 and I am getting a strange error since yesterday.

When compiling with Textmate I am getting Error Code 1 and in the Terminal there is this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/Boris/Library/Application 
Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/bin/texmate.py", line 1015, in
 status = command_parser.parse_stream() File "/Users/Boris/Library/Application 
Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/lib/parsing.py", line 763, in
 parse_stream return super(LaTexMkParser, self).parse_stream() 
File "/Users/Boris/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/lib/parsing.py", line 180, in parse_stream function(matching, line) 
File "/Users/Boris/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/lib/parsing.py", line 782,
 in start_latex fatal_error, number_errors, number_warnings = parser.parse_stream()
 File "/Users/Boris/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/lib/parsing.py", line 603, in parse_stream return super(LaTexParser, self).parse_stream() File "/Users/Boris/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/lib/parsing.py", line 187,
 in parse_stream line =
 self.get_rewrapped_line() 
File "/Users/Boris/Library/Application
Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/LaTeX.tmbundle/Support/lib/parsing.py",
line 135, in get_rewrapped_line statement += line.rstrip('\n')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 50:
 invalid continuation byte
```

I found out that if i comment 2 `\include{chapter}` of my chapters this will go away and it will work but i couldn't narrow it down to any of both chapters.

Also it will compile fine in pdflatex from the terminal....

Any help/clue is appreciated very much!

Comment: The error is from your editor rather than tex and main bit is `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position` which says that your input file claims to be UTF-8 but is not.

Comment: byte e4 is ä in latin1 if you have such an accented letter in your file encoded as byte xe4, then the file is latin1 (iso-8859-1) encoded not utf-8.

Comment: hmm I have plenty of ä, ü and ö in my document since it is german. i have set the encoding to utf8 and inputenc and i checked if the file ist uff8... but the eror is still showing up. and thank you for your fast reply !

Comment: well your editor seems to have found an ä that is not in UTF-8, I could not tell from that trace which file it was reading. It is giving the lines of the parser source not of the input.

Comment: does this mean that even though my files are encoded as utf8, they could include a single latin1 ö ä or ü ? this is madness ! especially when writing texts in german.

Comment: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/2656/wie-uberprufe-ich-die-standardeingabekodierung-in-meinem-editor

Comment: It means that the files are not (correctly) encoded in UTF8. that doesn't necessarily mean that they are not correct (it could be a bug in the parser) but that is what the error message _means_. Sorry I don't have the file or that editor so I guess I can't help any more than that.

Comment: Note answers that have been deleted indicate that it is a bug in the system rather than your file. I can not confirm but: https://github.com/textmate/latex.tmbundle/commit/4917508155c5412c0dbeec952354c2c479e56837

Comment: were you able to find a solution?!

Comment: Based on the diff that @DavidCarlisle showed, it may be trying to read a `.log` file as UTF-8. Does LaTeX guarantee any specific encoding for those?

Comment: @Boris if you found a solution to this problem, *please* post it because I'm having the same problem. I'm also writing my thesis and got stuck with this problem!